# Problems with state with Vue component and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a problem with the following simple Vue component. I'm just trying to get the v-if="isTouched" to rerender upon setting the setter (by firing the touch event). 
According to Vue dev tools the _isTouched variable is "undefined". From what I've understood variables like that shall automatically be included in the components data() block. This however doesnt seem to be the case. 
Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Best//M

```
<template>
    <div v-if="selectedProgramItem">
        {{isTouched}}
        <span v-if="isTouched">Unsaved changes</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="selectedProgramItem.title" />
        <button @click="touch()">Touch object</button>
    </div>

</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { ProgramItem } from '@/entities/ProgramItem';

@Component
export default class ProgramEditItemPane extends Vue {
    @Prop() private selectedProgramItem?: ProgramItem;

    _isTouched: boolean = false;

    private get isTouched(): boolean {
            return this._isTouched;
    }
    private set isTouched(val: boolean) {
        this._isTouched = val;
        // this._isTouched <<<<<<<<< == undefined here.
    }
    private touch() {
        this.isTouched = true;
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: The way you use your prop `selectedProgramItem` might cause a problem if it is undefined. Your _isTouched variable should indeed be defined in the component data. Can you post a reproductible example?

Comment: Try binding without the parentheses: `@click="touch"`. Not sure this will help, tho.

Comment: The actual firing of the event and the execution of the touch() function works fine. Its just that it seems that my private variable _isTouched always seem to stay as undefined. If i decorate it with @Prop it seems to work but it yields the following warning message:
[Vue warn]: The data property "_isTouched" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead.

But this isn't really a prop to my understanding this should be a "data" as its not passed from any other component to this one

Comment: I simplified it by removing the selectedProgramItem prop and the template parts associated with that prop. Still same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mentioned in this [Github issue comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2098#issuecomment-168091787):

> _ prefixed properties are reserved for Vue's internal properties.

This is also documented over [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data):

> Properties that start with _ or $ will not be proxied on the Vue
> instance because they may conflict with Vue’s internal properties and
> API methods. You will have to access them as vm.$data._property.

The solution is to change `_isTouched` to something like `isTouchedField`.